# How to pass the touches to view from scrollview

Tags: iphone, touch, scrollview, swipe, hittest

[image]

I have 3 tableviews placed upon scrollview at x = 0.0, x = 320.0 and x = 640.0.
When the user horizontally swipes the tableviews (as they are on top), I want to pass the swipe event to its superview and when the user vertically swipes tableviews the tableview must scroll vertically.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the touch from `UIScrollView`, use this code as a category:

```
@implementation UIScrollView (FixedApi)

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    NSLog(@"touch view = %@", [[touch view].class description]);
    if ([[[touch view].class description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellContentView"]) {
        //To pass the touch to UITableViewCell
    } else if ([[[touch view].class description] isEqualToString:@"UITableView"] && isHorizntalSCroll == true && pageNumber == 2) {
        //To pass the touch to UITableView

    } else if ([[[touch view].class description] isEqualToString:@"UIView"]) {
        //To pass the touch to UIView
    } else {
    [self.superview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; // or 1 nextResponder, depends
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ( !self.dragging ) [self.nextResponder.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

To determine the vertical/Horizontal scrolling, you can use this code:

.h file `<UIScrollViewDelegate>`

```
BOOL pageControlIsChangingPage;
CGPoint startPos;
int     scrollDirection;
int CX; //The width of the pages.
BOOL isHorizntalSCroll;
int pageNumber;
```

.m file

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate stuff
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {
    if (scrollDirection==0){//we need to determine direction
        //use the difference between positions to determine the direction.
        if (abs(startPos.x-scrollView.contentOffset.x)<abs(startPos.y-scrollView.contentOffset.y)){          
            NSLog(@"Vertical Scrolling");
            scrollDirection=1;
            isHorizntalSCroll = false;
            [scrollView setPagingEnabled:NO];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Horitonzal Scrolling");
            scrollDirection=2;
            isHorizntalSCroll = ture;
            [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
        }
    }

    if (scrollDirection==1) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(startPos.x,scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:NO];
    } else if (scrollDirection==2){
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x,startPos.y) animated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {
    if (pageControlIsChangingPage) {
        return;
    }

    CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    pageControl.currentPage = page;
    pageNumber = page;
    NSLog(@"page number = %d",page);
    if (page == 3 || page == 0) {
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CX, personalInfo.frame.size.height + 100)];
    } else {
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CX, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
    }

    pageControlIsChangingPage = NO;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PageControl stuff
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    /*
     *  Change the scroll view
     */
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pageControl.currentPage;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

    /*
     *  When the animated scrolling finishings, scrollViewDidEndDecelerating will turn this off
     */
    pageControlIsChangingPage = YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollViews{
    startPos = scrollView.contentOffset;
    scrollDirection=0;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollViews willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (decelerate) {
        scrollDirection=3;
    }
}
```

That's it,

Comment: This answer uses private API and global state and overrides UIScrollView's internal methods for all scroll views in your process with questionable logic. This answer is absolutely terrible and should never be used.

Answer (score 0):

disable horizontal scroling for each tableview via IB or code and set the `contentsize` of the base scroll view to be 960,`heightOfTableview` and you should be just fine... this should get you going.